# What is the bracket wrapped colon notation in Nginx server blocks?

Tags: nginx

I often see this in Nginx server blocks but I have no idea what it means and it doesn't Google well.

```
server {
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
}
```

What does the `[::]` mean?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is the IPv6 notation for all interfaces.

Comment: More specifically `::` is `in6addr_any`, the IPv6 analogue of `inaddr_any` or `0.0.0.0`. It appears in brackets to disambiguate it from the `:` which divides it from the port number.

Comment: So that means "listen for any ipv6 address"?

Comment: In nginx at least it means to listen to the dual-protocol socket that handles both IPv4 and IPv6.